# How to set a list to 100% height?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I set a list to be 100% height so it fills the full free space on a site?

My page looks like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MeinView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                title: 'MyApp',
                id: 'StartAnsicht',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'list',
                        docked: 'top',
                        height: 200,
                        ui: 'round',
                        itemTpl: [
                            '<div>{titel}: {inhalt}</div>'
                        ],
                        store: 'EintragStore'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        docked: 'bottom',
                        id: 'NeuerEintrag',
                        itemId: 'mybutton1',
                        ui: 'action',
                        text: 'New'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onNeuerEintragTap',
                event: 'tap',
                delegate: '#NeuerEintrag'
            }
        ]
    },

    onNeuerEintragTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        this.push(Ext.create("MyApp.view.AddAnsicht", {
            title: "New Item"
        }));
    }

});
```

actually the height is set to 200, but I want to be it automatically 100% height and fill the free space so that I see just:

- Top bar,
- List with all free space,
- button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, what I can do it with a [VBOX](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/docs/Ext.layout.VBox.2/viewer.html)